# Exporting dates from Access to CSV - remove time

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to export a simple query with dates. When I export, access wants to display the time component of the date.  Stumped on how to just export date.  I am using O365

Comment: Date values have time component? Try extracting date part: `DateValue([datefield])`. Edit question to show sample data and attempted query.

Comment: Use `FORMAT()` function like `FORMAT([MyDateTime],"mm/dd/yyyy")` to show desired date format without time.